# Flutter desktop / go-flutter-desktop How to get path of Excel.exe on Windows Platform

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I am running Flutter desktop app on Windows and I use go-flutter-desktop. 
 
I would like to open Excel.exe when user click button with correct path

```
String win10Path = 'C:\\progra~1\\MIF5BA~1\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE';
String win7Path = 'C:\\progra~2\\micros~1\\Office14\\EXCEL.EXE';
```

Windows regisgry has Excel path information

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe
```

What's the correct way to get path of Excel.exe on Windows with Dart?
Need a sold solution to open MS Office, Lotus Notes, PDF viewer, Windows Media Player...
Thank you very much